# Put $M$ balls into $N$ boxes, then randomly select $k$ boxes, what is the distribution of the least-loaded box's load?

Tags: probability

1. We first put $M$ balls into $N$ boxes at random,
2. After all the balls have been placed, we then randomly select $k$ boxes from the $N$ boxes.
3. Among the $k$ boxes, let $X$ denote the number of balls in the least-loaded box, what is the distribution of $X$?

Comment: $X$ has a positive probability of not being well defined if $k \lt N$

Comment: @Henry Can you explain a little more or give some reference?

Comment: All of the balls might have gone into the other $N-k$ boxes.  Then all $k$ boxes will be empty and there will not be a "non-empty least-loaded box".  Though I suppose you could define the minimum of an empty set to be $+\infty$

Comment: @Henry Maybe I didn't express my question clearly, I have edited this question. Please take a look.

Comment: No - the issue is still there.  For example, suppose $M=4, N=3, k=2$.  Then there is probability $\frac1{3^5}$ you will put all four balls in the third box and then choose the first and the second boxes to look at.  Both would be empty, so there would not be a "non-empty least-loaded box" out of the first and second, and so $X$ would not be defined

Comment: @Henry I see, then I remove the "non-empty" constraint.

Comment: Note that the randomness in your second step doesn't have any effect, as the first step already ensures that the distribution is symmetric under box permutation. So you may just take the first $k$ boxes without changing the result.

Comment: @celtschk hmmm, you are right!